# Why does Japanese lack word wrapping?

Tags: words, orthography

Why does Japanese ([more or less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_breaking_rules_in_East_Asian_languages#Line_breaking_rules_in_Japanese_text_.28Kinsoku_Shori.29)) lack word wrapping, with even words written in katakana broken up by new lines?

Comment: @SerialDownvoter: I've noticed you. If the automatic script doesn't reverse it, I'll flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: Why should Japanese have word wrapping? Your question is similar to asking “Why is Hebrew written from right to left?”

Comment: You ask "why Japanese lacks word wrapping" and at the same time include a link pointing to standards of word wrapping in Japanese and even a bold **Word wrap rules** heading. What is your question?

Comment: Maybe because Japanese doesn't have spaces?

Comment: My guess is influence from the Chinese typesetting/printing tradition.

Comment: @macraf the question title is slightly simplified, with the body containing more qualifiers. That's because I wanted to make the title concise.

Comment: My 二円: I think this could be expanded into several very good questions, but I think it is a bit unclear in its current state.

Answer (score 1):

If the text has been laid out properly by a designer the words will wrap right after the particle for more natural flow (が、を、は etc).
For a websites in Japanese, because there is no whitespace between characters the sentence is treated as one 'word' and will break wherever it needs to.

Comment: Regarding your comment on websites: I have seen a lot of websites and emails where the author manually breaks up sentences to a specific length.

Comment: ... and this kind of "typewriter" treatment of text is an absolute bane for any kind of automated text processing.  >:-(